# Subset a matrix by dimension names in a vector R

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a vector nodenames as

```
nodenames <- c("A","B","C","T","N","Z")
```

I have a square sparse matrix with dimnames as

```
Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:4149962] 1 2 3 4 5 9 11 12 13 14 ...
  ..@ p       : int [1:3417] 0 1702 2710 3935 5411 6719 8141 9822 9822 11515 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 3416 3416
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3416] "A" "B" "AAL" "T" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3416] "A" "B" "AAL" "T" ...
  ..@ x       : num [1:4149962] 2 1 1 3 1 1 2 19 3 2 ...
  ..@ factors : list()
```

How can I produce a subset of this matrix with dimnames in nodenames?

Comment: Come on Tom. Post it as an answer.

Comment: It would have been a very big surprise to find the "[" had not been implemented with Matrix objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Tim Riffe's answer is the most direct. If the user were unsure whether the 'nodenames' vector were a subset of both the rownames() and the colnames() values, then this might be a bit safer:

```
nodenames <- c("A","ZZ","C","T","N","Z")

seq1 <- seq(1:100)
mat1 <- matrix(seq1, 10)
rownames(mat1)<-c("G","A","B","F","C","D","T","N","Z","J")
colnames(mat1)<-c("G","A","B","F","C","D","T","N","Z","J")
mat1[rownames(mat1) %in% nodenames, colnames(mat1) %in% nodenames]
#----------
   A  C  T  N  Z
A 12 42 62 72 82
C 15 45 65 75 85
T 17 47 67 77 87
N 18 48 68 78 88
Z 19 49 69 79 89
```

For the amended question for objects of class-dgCMatrix I am getting sensible results using the same methods:

```
(m <- Matrix(c(0,0,2:0), 3,5))
3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] . 1 . . 2
[2,] . . 2 . 1
[3,] 2 . 1 . .

 m@Dimnames <- list(X=letters[1:3], Y=LETTERS[1:5])
 m["a", "B"]
# [1] 1
 m["a", c("A","B")]
# A B 
# 0 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Sorry I didn't describe my problem clearly.Actually I am working on a sparse matrix, the simple subseting way seems not working.

Comment: Given my success with the same methods, you will need to post a reproducible example that shows exactly how this is "not working".

Comment: works for me. Your example @Seen isn't sparse, but it works when the class is "dgCMatrix" of the Matrix package

Comment: Thanks. I checked and found mat1[nodenames, nodenames] is not working since some of the rownames are not in nodenames, but mat1[rownames(mat1) %in% nodenames, colnames(mat1) %in% nodenames]
is working.

Comment: Doesn't subset the dgCMatrix object, just converts to a standard matrix, then subsets.

Answer (score 6):

You can subset matrices based by index numbers, by dimension names (via a character vector, such as your `nodenames`), by logical vectors, and possibly other things that are beyond me.

```
mat1[nodenames, nodenames]
  A  B  C  T  N  Z
A 12 22 42 62 72 82
B 13 23 43 63 73 83
C 15 25 45 65 75 85
T 17 27 47 67 77 87
N 18 28 48 68 78 88
Z 19 29 49 69 79 89
```

or:

```
mat1[which(rownames(mat1)%in% nodenames), which(colnames(mat1) %in% nodenames)]
mat1[rownames(mat1)%in% nodenames, colnames(mat1) %in% nodenames]
```